# devise - before filter in users controller and users scope in routes, correct implementation?, using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I use devise for authentication.  In the users controller, I have:

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

In the config/routes file, I have:

```
#DEVISE
devise_for :users
authenticated :user do
 resources :user
end
```

Do I really need the 'before_filter :authenticate_user!` in the users controller?  Isn't it duplicative?

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: Yeah! You'll need that, but on application_controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, having that code in both the controller and routes file is redundant. It's totally up to you and your design philosophy whether you go with authenticating in the controller files or routes file, but choosing one path will help you stay organized when your app grows.

[Here's a good explanation from the Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-resource-actions-that-require-authentication-using-routes.rb) of the difference between using the `before_filter` in controllers and and using `authenticate`, `authenticated`, and `unauthenticated` with resources.

Comment: Thank you.  Good explanation!  I'm accepting your answer.